# Picked up object is shaking when moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a `GameObject` that is placed in front of the camera, so whenever the player picks up an object, it will be placed in the `GameObejct`'s location. but whenever I move while I'm picking up an object, the object shakes. How would I prevent that from happening?

```cs
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (currentlyPickedUpObject != null)
    {
        currentDist = Vector3.Distance(PickupParent.position, pickupRB.position);
        currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothStep(minSpeed, maxSpeed, currentDist / maxDistance);
        currentSpeed *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        pickupRB.transform.position = PickupParent.position;
        Vector3 direction = PickupParent.position - pickupRB.position;
        pickupRB.velocity = direction.normalized * currentSpeed;
    }
}
```

```cs
if (PickingUp)
{
    if (currentlyPickedUpObject == null)
    {
        if (lookObject != null)
        {
            PickupObject();
            if (lookObject.CompareTag("TargetObj") && !targetObjectsList.Contains(lookObject.gameObject))
            {
                if (aSource)
                {
                    aSource.Play();
                }

                targetObjectsList.Add(lookObject.gameObject);
                if (targetObjectsList.Count == targetObjects.Length)
                {
                    winUI.SetActive(true);
                    Time.timeScale = 0f;
                    //SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
                    //Time.timeScale = 1f;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // pickupRB.transform.position = PickupParent.position;
        BreakConnection();
        HoldingItemIcon.SetActive(false);
        InteractIcon.SetActive(false);
    }
}

PickingUp = false;

public void BreakConnection()
{
    pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
    currentlyPickedUpObject = null;
    lookObject = null;
    physicsObject.pickedUp = false;
    currentDist = 0;
    pickupRB.useGravity = true;
}

public void PickupObject()
{
    physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();
    currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;
    pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
    physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;

    pickupRB.isKinematic = true;
    //  pickupRB.transform.position = PickupParent.position;
    pickupRB.transform.parent = PickupParent.transform;

    //StartCoroutine(physicsObject.PickUp()); 
}
```

and here is the inspector of pickable objects:
[image]

and here is the code attached to the pickable objects:

```cs
public class PhysicsObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float waitOnPickup = 0.1f;
    public float breakForce = 35f;
    [HideInInspector] public bool pickedUp = false;
    [HideInInspector] public ThePlayerInteractions playerInteractions;


    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (pickedUp)
        {
            if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > breakForce)
            {
                playerInteractions.BreakConnection();
            }
        }
    }

    //this is used to prevent the connection from breaking when you just picked up the object as it sometimes fires a collision with the ground or whatever it is touching
    public IEnumerator PickUp()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(waitOnPickup);
        pickedUp = true;
    }
}
```

other than shaking, the picked-up objects lose their colliders for some reason, they go through any objects they hit. what is the best way to avoid these issues when the objects are being held?

Comment: You could try making the picked up object a child of the pickup parent `pickupRB.transform.SetParent(PickupParent.transform)` and then remove the lines where you update the position in the fixed update.  It's probably shaking because you only ever update its position during fixed update, but regular old update runs much more often.

Comment: so I tried adding this line in my Update() and I removed the FixedUpdate(). Now, the object does not shake but it behaves weirdly. it is not flying in front of the player rather it is on the floor and being dragged when I move

Comment: Cameras render in update, physics updates on fixed update, and the two basically never happen at the same time. I think you need to mark your rigidbody to interpolate to smooth the motion between frames, but you also keep snapping the rigidbody and setting velocities. If you want to control the rigidbody to that degree of detail, just turn physics off. You and the physics system are fighting.

Comment: the rigidbody of the objects is already set to interpolate.  I'm using a character controller for my player (I don't know if that would change anything). I I tried setting the gravity to false when the object is carried, but it still kind of shakes when moving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:EDIT:

Three viable options seem to exist, so I'll cover those and then you can choose whatever works best for you. Ultimately I still think the root cause here is that you're trying to interact with the physics object (`Rigidbody`) while at the same time enabling Unity to interact with the physics object. The ways around this all revolve around either disabling Unity's ability to interact with it (fixing the constraints), or removing your interaction (adding a FixedJoint), or trying to not interact with it at the same time (moving your interaction to Update).

## Option 1: Fixed Joint

[image: Fixed Joints]

Instead of doing the steps to update positions and velocities, just add a `FixedJoint` and then remove that joint on drop:

```
private FixedJoint fixedJoint;
public void BreakConnection()
{
    Destroy(fixedJoint);
}

public void PickupObject()
{
    fixedJoint = gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
    fixedJoint.connectedBody = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
```

## Option 2: Move Positioning Code to Update

[image: Update instead of FixedUpdate]

If you do this in `Update()` instead of `FixedUpdate()` then this also appears to remove the jitter, but there's a chance that you might not be getting the physics interactions that you want, so definitely test with this before committing to it:

```
private void Update()
{
    fixedJoint.connectedBody
    if (PickupParent != null)
    {
        currentDist = Vector3.Distance(PickupParent.position, pickupRB.position);
        currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothStep(minSpeed, maxSpeed, currentDist / maxDistance);
        currentSpeed *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        pickupRB.transform.position = PickupParent.position;
        Vector3 direction = PickupParent.position - pickupRB.position;
        pickupRB.velocity = direction.normalized * currentSpeed;
    }
}
```

## Option 3: Apply Constraints

[image: Add Rigidbody constraints]

This would require you to continue to do the updating (which you can avoid by adding a `FixedJoint`, in Option 1 above) but doesn't create the joint, so it leaves the `pickupParent` alone. Adding a `FixedJoint` will link the pickup and parent together which may result in pushback on the parent if/when the pickup collides with something.

You can just use the all/none constraint options or you could cache the existing constraints and reset them on break. I'll include that option here because it's (a tiny bit) more involved.

```
private RigidbodyConstraints priorConstraints;    // <--- NEW
public void BreakConnection()
{
    pickupRB.constraints = priorConstraints;    // <--- NEW
    currentlyPickedUpObject = null;
    lookObject = null;
    physicsObject.pickedUp = false;
    currentDist = 0;
    pickupRB.useGravity = true;
}

public void PickupObject()
{
    physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();
    currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;
    pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    priorConstraints = pickupRB.constraints;    // <--- NEW
    pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;    // <--- NEW
    physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;

    pickupRB.isKinematic = true;
    //  pickupRB.transform.position = PickupParent.position;
    pickupRB.transform.parent = PickupParent.transform;

    //StartCoroutine(physicsObject.PickUp()); 
}
```

:Original post:

I still think you're having issues because you're trying to manually override the physics system by setting the position and velocity. Try disabling the rigidbody when you pick it up and adding it as a child of the PickupParent. You'll keep whatever colliders are present and as long as the PickupParent has a ribidbody itself then this is a valid approach because rigibodies use the sum of all colliders on all child game objects.

You should only have one rigidbody on an object tree and it should be at the root level, so I'm assuming your pickup items are all root objects with no parents.

Since you're attaching them to you there really isn't anything to do in FixedUpdate anymore:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (currentlyPickedUpObject != null)
    {
        //currentDist = Vector3.Distance(PickupParent.position, pickupRB.position);
        //currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothStep(minSpeed, maxSpeed, currentDist / maxDistance);
        //currentSpeed *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        //pickupRB.transform.position = PickupParent.position;
        //Vector3 direction = PickupParent.position - pickupRB.position;
        //pickupRB.velocity = direction.normalized * currentSpeed;
    }
}
```

You haven't provided the code for pickup, but I believe you can effectively disable the rigidbody without deleting it by setting isKinematic to true, so change its parent and set that on pickup then remove the parent and clear isKinematic on BreakConnection.

```
void PickupObject()
{
    pickupRb.isKinematic = true;
    pickupRb.transform.parent = pickupParent.transform;
    // other stuff to do here
}

void BreakConnection()
{
    pickupRb.isKinematic = false;
    pickupRb.transform.parent = null;
    // other stuff to do here
}
```

If you're continuing to have jitter then the other thing to do would be to check the Interpolate setting on the pickupParent because that's the object you're snapping to (here and in your original code).

Comment: So I tried to apply everything you mentioned. But adding rigidbody to the pickupParent made it behave oddly. Now the pickupParent is misplaced it appears behind the player, not in front. and every time I pick up an object the position of the pickupParent change and goes further. and the picked-up object is not following the player(not sticking to the middle of the screen) the player can walk pass it.

Comment: @Okashi can you share more details about object you pick up? Do you have at least one collider attached? Are there rigidbodies in children? It's hard to help debug this if I can't recreate your setup.

Comment: Yes they have both rigidbodies and colliders

Comment: I'm going to edit and share more info in the question

Comment: I added the pickup() and all other info

Comment: @Okashi - What does the `Cube (3)` hierarchy look like? Are there child gameObjects there?

Comment: it is just a 3D object by itself it is not a parent or a child of any other object.

Comment: So do you have any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: @Okashi I'm sorry I've been slammed lately and haven't had a chance to come back to this. I'll look at it first thing tomorrow, but before I do - what is moving the pickupParent? I don't think it should matter in your original case because you're not actually coupled to it, but it's strange that the parent is acting weird. Do you have a short video showing the problem? I'd like to recreate your issue before I try to work on a solution because I might be solving a different problem. Maybe a Git repo you could share that recreates the problem? Also have you considered a fixed joint?

Comment: Yes, I agree it is hard to deliver an issue like this. but I don't know how else to do it. No, I haven't considered a fixed joint. the pickupParent is where the objects should be placed when they are picked. I will try to share a video or GIF here.

Comment: @Okashi I updated the answer here to include three workarounds. Please let me know if any of these work for you! :D

Comment: Thank you for your effort. it is the most appreciated. I just have a question before I start trying these options. Do these options make the picked-up object lose its collider and go through walls and other objects?

Comment: @Okashi - Nope, all of these options keep all the colliders and keep the rigidbody on the pickup object, so there should be no issues there. As I point out at some point above, if you use a `FixedJoint` to attach the pickup object to the `PickupParent` then the two are treated as if they're welded together, which could cause some upstream issues with however you have your `PickupParent` structured/attached. The other two options (fixing the constraints and moving to `Update()`) leave the pickup object as its own item and so there's no mechanism to transmit reactionary forces to the parent.

Comment: @Okashi - did you get a chance to try this? Did it work? I keep refreshing, hoping to hear something lol

Comment: I'm sorry I tried only the first two options. Moving to Update() made it better, the picked-up object doesn't jitter when moving forward, left, right and backward. but it jitters a little when moving the mouse (mouse look) and for some reason, the objects lose their colliders when they are picked. and For Fixed Joint, when I used this I couldn't move the player properly it is like its movement became limited and when dropping the object the player behaved really weirdly (the player rotates in the air).

Comment: I will try the last option now and give you feedback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245511/discussion-between-okashi-and-chuck).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to directly change the transform position in your code:

```
pickupRB.transform.position = PickupParent.position;
```

But it's not a right way to handle rigidbodies movement. It is the reason of shaking, and, moreover, it causes huge overhead due to recalculating all the rigidbody physics each time you set transform position directly. Instead of doing this, use rigidbody.MovePosition along with making the rididbody kinematic while it is attached to the player:

```
pickupRB.MovePosition(PickupParent.position)
```

To make it easier, you could also use the FixedJoint, as Chuck suggests

Comment: I actually tried `MovePosition` when experimenting to find a solution and it didn't work either! At least, not in `FixedUpdate`. Moving the transform in `Update` does work though.

Comment: This did not work for me either